# Using Vb.Net how do I check if section/subdivision exist and add their value into a xml doc?

Tags: xml, vb.net

My function is working but not as I expect it to. The problem is that when Section and Subvision are not found in the object aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode , I get an error NullReference Exception was unhandled by user code. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

For that reason, because the two elements are optional, I would like to check if they exist before adding their value into the xml inside the object objXmlRequestMessageDoc.

The if statement I used in my function did not work. When it found Section element, it did not check for Subdivision.

How do I check for both and add them if they exist. If they do not exist, I do not need to do anything and should not throw an error since they are optional.
Object aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode has this xml in it

```
<ns:GetStatutesRequest xmlns:ns="http://www.courts.state.mn.us/StatuteService/1.0">
<ns:Statute>
    <ns:Chapter>169</ns:Chapter>
            <!--Optional:-->
    <ns:Section>191</ns:Section>
            <!--Optional:-->
    <ns:Subdivision>a</ns:Subdivision>
</ns:Statute>
```

The following output in the objXmlRequestMessageDoc object is correct but this does not work when Section and or Subdivision are not found in the object aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.

```
<ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest xmlns:ns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/service/4.0">
    <ns1:BasicSearchCriteria xmlns:ns1="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/messages/4.0">
        <ns2:Chapter xmlns:ns2="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0"/169</ns2:Chapter>>
        <ns2:Section xmlns:ns2="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0"/>191</ns2:Chapter>
        <ns2:Subdivision xmlns:ns2="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0"/>a</ns2:Chapter>
    </ns1:BasicSearchCriteria>
</ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest>
```

Here is my function

```
 Function GetStatutesByChapter(ByVal aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode As XmlNode, ByVal aobjXMLNameSpaceManager As XmlNamespaceManager, ByVal aobjBroker As ServiceCatalog.Library.v4.Broker) As XmlDocument
        Dim objXmlRequestMessageDoc As XmlDocument
        Dim objXmlResponseMessageDoc As XmlDocument
        Dim intCount As Integer

        aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("Chapter found.", 1)

        objXmlResponseMessageDoc = New XmlDocument
        'Add the first element into the document GetStatuteByChapter with its namespace
        objXmlResponseMessageDoc.AppendChild(objXmlResponseMessageDoc.CreateElement("BasicSearchQueryResponse", "http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/service/4.0"))

     'Create the BCA request message
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc = New XmlDocument
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("ns")))
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("ns1")))
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest/ns1:BasicSearchCriteria", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns2:Chapter", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("st")))

        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest/ns1:BasicSearchCriteria", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns2:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("st")))
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest/ns1:BasicSearchCriteria", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns2:Subdivision", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("st")))

        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria/st:Chapter", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Chapter", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria/st:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria/st:Subdivision", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Subdivision", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText

        'check if there is a section and or subdivision if it is there then set the value
        'If Not (aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText) Is Nothing Then
        '    objXmlRequestMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria/st:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
        'End If

        'check if there is a section and or subdivision if it is there then set the value
        aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseSnapshot(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.OuterXml, "Request Message", 1)

        'Call the BCA service
        intCount = 0

        'Count how many Statute node found
        CType(objXmlResponseMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ss:GetStatutesResponse/ss:StatutesXml/ss:Statutes", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager), System.Xml.XmlElement).SetAttribute("totalCount", CStr(intCount))
        Return objXmlResponseMessageDoc
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this with the following two if statements

```
'check if there is a section and or subdivision if it is there then set the value
        If Not (aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager) Is Nothing) Then
            objXmlRequestMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria/st:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
        End If

        If Not (aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Subdivision", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager) Is Nothing) Then
            objXmlRequestMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria/st:Subdivision", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Subdivision", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
        End If
```